# Advice on how to make my regex string matching in R faster

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, runtime, stringr

I'm doing string matching in R that is basically a more complex version of the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_restaurants <- tibble(restaurant = c("MCDONALD 'S ON FRANKLIN ST",
                                        "NEW JERSEY WENDYS",
                                        "8/25/19 RUTH CHRIS",
                                        "MELTING - POT 9823i3",
                                        "BOB & DAVE'S CAFE"
                                        )
                         )

cheap <- c(
  "MCDONALD\\s*'*\\s*S",
  "WENDY\\s*'*\\s*S",
  "BOB\\s*(AND)?'*(N)?&*\\s*DAVE\\s*'*\\s*S\\s*-*'*#*\\.*\\**\\s*CAFE"
  ) %>%
  str_c(collapse="|")

expensive <- c(
  "RUTH CHRIS",
  "MELTING\\s*-*'*#*\\.*\\**\\s*POT"
  ) %>%
  str_c(collapse="|")

my_restaurants_matched <- my_restaurants %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
    str_detect(restaurant, cheap) ~ "CHEAP",
    str_detect(restaurant, expensive) ~ "EXPENSIVE"
    ))
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
> my_restaurants_matched
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  restaurant                 category 
  <chr>                      <chr>    
1 MCDONALD 'S ON FRANKLIN ST CHEAP    
2 NEW JERSEY WENDYS          CHEAP    
3 8/25/19 RUTH CHRIS         EXPENSIVE
4 MELTING - POT 9823i3       EXPENSIVE
5 BOB & DAVE'S CAFE          CHEAP
```

I say "more complex" because there are many more categories than `cheap` and `expensive`, and the vector for each category is much longer (the longest ones have around 200 elements before being collapsed).  They also contain more regular expressions - they actually start off as normal looking strings, then go through a function that replaces every whitespace with something like `\\s*'*\\s*S\\s*-*'*#*\\.*\\**\\s*`, every apostrophe is something like `\\s*'*\\s*S`, etc.

This worked great for me for a while - intially `my_restaurants` had about 2500 rows, they were all categorized in about an hour, which was fine for me.  Now, `my_restaurants` has about 6500 rows, and my code is now hasn't finishing categorizing all the rows after 12+ hours.

First - I would expect that when a dataset becomes 2-3x larger, code like this would take 2-3x longer to run.  Instead, it seems to be taking an exponentially longer time.  I don't really know what goes on "under the hood" in R - can anyone explain why this happens in a down-to-earth way?

Second - does anyone have any ideas on how I could speed things up here?

Comment: what about chopping the df and running the regex detect on the chunks?

Comment: @Eric Is it really that simple? I guess my intuition says that it matches the same number of rows either way, so why would it go any faster if it matches them as 10 dfs instead of 1?  But if there are under-the-hood reasons why that works, I welcome that

Comment: I noticed the same thing.  could be some memory overhead that makes it go O(n^2).  use `split` to split the df into chunks and then operate on the list of dfs with `lapply`. finally, `dplyr::bind_rows` on the list will stitch back to one df.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential slowing down probably has to do with either the `case_when` or the `mutate`, and likely does not relate to the str_detect. Just run two separate `str_detect` functions (one for cheap and one for expensive) on a vector-version of your column, then make a data frame from them and complete the final column with logic.

```r
vec1 <- my_restaurants$restaurant

cheap1 <- str_detect(vec1, cheap)

expensive1 <- str_detect(vec1, expensive)

df <- tibble(restaurant = vec1,
             cheap = cheap1,
             expensive = expensive1) %>%
  mutate(category = if_else(cheap, "cheap", if_else(expensive, "expensive", NA_character_)))
```